# PyQt4 QPushButton text and icon alignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, qpushbutton

I want to create a button with text and icon, for example **Next =>**, and I'm using QPushButton.

I tried to do the following:

```
btn2 = QtGui.QPushButton('Next',self)
btn2.setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap("next.png")))
```

but I got:

[image: button picture]

I want the arrow (icon) to appear on the right side of the text ("Next"), or below.
Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`setLayoutDirection()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#setLayoutDirection)

```
btn2.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
```

It can sometimes look a little weird, and you'll have to play with the button size and margins to get it to look right.

Answer (score 6):

For some reason, `setLayoutDirection()` didn't work for me (PyQt5). I'm using the following option:

```
btn2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton { text-align: left; }")
```

This works pretty good. You can find more options for style sheets on this link: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html